# Accessing home directory of encryted ubuntu. Its on a USB stick and refuses to boot

Tags: boot, usb, encryption

I have a ubuntu system that refuses to boot. I cant seem to fix it.

The system is on a USB stick and I need to access the home directory
on it, but it is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the steps for [Recovering Your Data Manually](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering%20Your%20Data%20Manually) at Ubuntu documentation.
It follows with the section on [**Live CD method of opening a encrypted home directory**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Live%20CD%20method%20of%20opening%20a%20encrypted%20home%20directory).